# Card Layout panel is not rendering in Sencha Touch 2.2

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have developed an app using sencha touch 2.0, now i upgraded the app to sencha touch 2.2.
It is not working.
I have a container(layout=card) as shown below:

```
Ext.define("InfoImage.view.viewWorkitem.ViewWorkitemView", {
extend:'Ext.Container',
requires:[
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.List'
],
xtype:'workitems',
layout:'card',
cardSwitchAnimation:'slide',
config:{
    fullscreen:true,
    cls:'hboxpanel',
    items:[

       {
            xtype:'workItemPanel',
            flex:3
       } 
    ]
} });
```

**workItemPanel is as below:**

```
Ext.define("InfoImage.view.viewWorkitem.WorkitemPanel", {
extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
requires:[
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.List'
],
xtype:'workItemPanel',
id:'workItemId',
config:{


    layout : 'card',
    style:'border-radius: 10px;',
    navigationBar:{
        hidden:'true'
    },

    items:[ ]
}  });
```

This is working fine in sencha tocuh 2.0, Its not in 2.2
throwing an error **Uncaught TypeError: Object card has no method 'onItemAdd'**

what changes have to be done to make it work using sencha touch 2.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your configurations such as `layout:'card'`, `cardSwitchAnimation:'slide'` inside the `config` block:

```
config:{
    layout:'card',
    cardSwitchAnimation:'slide',
    fullscreen:true,
    cls:'hboxpanel',
    items:[

       {
            xtype:'workItemPanel',
            flex:3
       } 
    ]
}
```

Same way for your `id:'workItemId'` in the second view:

```
config:{
    id:'workItemId',
    layout : 'card',
    style:'border-radius: 10px;',
    navigationBar:{
         hidden:'true'
    },

    items:[ ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. :)
But the same code worked while using Sencha touch 2.0 
Sencha 2.2 has become stricter in terms of syntax?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But normally, it's a good habit and correct way to put your configurations inside the `config` block :)